# unable to display result on view page when the URL contain parameters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch the data from database based on the URL parameters. for the purpose of updating the table. the query was executed successfully without any problem. this fetching values displayed properly in controller but i can't able to print on view page

```
My controller:
public function edit_staff(){
  $userid =  $this->uri->segment(4);
  if (empty($userid))
        {
            show_404();
        }
 $data['staffs']=$this->Admin->edit_staffs($userid);
  print_r($data['staffs']);
  echo $data['staffs']['id'];
$this->load->view('admin/dashboard/edit_staff', $data);

}

My model:
function edit_staffs($userid){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('staffs');
    $this->db->where('id',$userid);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->row_array();
return $result;
}

My view shows:
Unable to load the requested file: admin/dashboard/edit_staff.php

URL for view page:
http://localhost/groport/admin/dashboard/edit_staff/18
```

i expect to show the view page and print staff detail

Comment: please check the requested file 'edit_staff.php' exists in the view folder (application/views/admin/dashboard).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that file `application/views/admin/dashboard/edit_staff.php` exists.

Check CI [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/views.html) for more details about CI Views